# Mysql error 1046: No database selected

Tags: php, java, mysql, sql, linux

¡Buenas, estaba siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YggXN_xJKbs) para la instalación de LAMP y poder seguir aprendiendo el mundillo de JDBB.

EL problema me surge a la hora de crear un usuario root desde consola con el siguiente comando:

```
update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("pass") where user = 'root';
```

El error que me sale es:

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

De momento ando algo perdido, agradecería mucho a un buen samaritano que me eche una mano sobre como lidiar con esto o porque me brinca ese error si se supone que es la primera vez que instalo estas tecnologías.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

El sistema te está indicando que no has seleccionado una BBDD donde realizar la acción. En MySQL debes hacer ese primer paso siempre.

En el caso de que tengas una BBDD ya creada, solo debes usar:

```sql
use nombre_bbdd
```

Si aún no has creado ninguna, primero deberás hacer:

```sql
create database nombre_bbdd
```

Y a continuación, usar el comando anteriormente comentado:

```sql
use nombre_bbdd
```

Comment: ¡Te lo agradezco mucho, en un momento mismo lo intento!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas creando un usuario pero sin indicarle la base de datos correspondiente.

Para crear una base de datos:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

En caso de tener la base de datos ya creada, tienes que indicarle que la vas a usar:

```
USE database_name;
```

El orden correcto quedaria asi:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
USE database_name;
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("pass") WHERE user = 'root';
```

Espero que sea de utilidad!

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias amigo!, lo intentaré enseguida.