# Hola! Tengo que crear una tabla en MYSQL pero me da error code 1046 Que estaria haciendo mal?

Tags: mysql

Tengo que crear una tabla en MYSQL pero me da error code 1046 Que estaria haciendo mal?
Este es el codigo que quiero ejecutar
CREATE TABLE tabla_1(
idtabla1 INT,
nombretabla1 VARCHAR(60),
fechatabla1 DATE
)

Comment: CREATE TABLE tabla_1(
idtabla1 INT,
nombretabla1 VARCHAR(60),
fechatabla1 DATE
)

Comment: El error 1046 de `MySQL` indica que no tienes seleccionada la base de datos. Revisa estos ejemplos en [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp) y consulta un poco la documentación de `MySQL`. O tal vez [estas respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253217/mysql-error-1046-no-database-selected) te lo aclaren un poco más.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mysql error 1046: No database selected](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253217/mysql-error-1046-no-database-selected)